# Interrupting a rabbinical mitzvah to perform a Biblical mitzvah

Tags: halacha-theory, derabanan, deorayta

In general, one does not interrupt a mitzvah (with the exception of Torah study) in order to do another mitzvah. However, [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12286/1516) answer, in its citation of the Ran, alludes to some complications of this precept in view of whether the mitzvot are rabbinical or Biblical.

It is not clear, however, whether one should interrupt the performance of a rabbinical mitzvah (or, say, a minhag) to do a Torah mitzvah. Is there a rule about this?

Related:

[Interrupting Amida for a Mitzvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37563/interrupting-amida-for-a-mitzvah)

[Which mitzvos exempt which mitzvos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/which-mitzvos-exempt-which-mitzvos)

Related, possible duplicate, not sure:

[Can a rabbincal mitzvah (that is currently being done) override a bibilical mitzvah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59456/can-a-rabbincal-mitzvah-that-is-currently-being-done-override-a-bibilical-mitz)

Comment: I wonder if saving a life is considered a Biblical mitzvah? If so, that certainly presents a pretty general case.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the quesiton you linked to?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you notice in the comments in the question I linked, it is not clear (to anyone) what exactly that question was saying and so no one could answer it. I'm not sure what one does re: site policy in cases like these. I think my question is pretty clear and answerable, and certainly some question on this topic belongs on this site.

Comment: @msh210 See above, not sure...

Comment: Perhaps the duplication should be reversed? @DoubleAA

Comment: The other question is currently open.  If it's unclear, shouldn't it be closed?  (I don't have a current opinion on its merits.)